# SQL query - Join two tables bringing back only lowest price Continued

Tags: sql, sql-server

Further to my earlier post today which was very swiftly answered by a_horse_with_no_name. (thank you so much for that) I have now realised that I need to return the value of an additional column from the boat_prices table. As a recap:

I have two MSSQL tables as follows:

```
boat_data

boat_prices
```

Boat data houses rows of data about boats. Each boat has a unique ID (pricingRef) Boat prices houses rows of rental prices for each boat and can have any number of rows for each boat. Each row also has a pricingRef value. Example data in the boat_prices table might be:

```
ID > pricingRef > pricingDescription > seasonDescription > price

1 > ASD1 > fullDay > lowSeason > 1500
2 > ASD1 > fullDay > midSeason > 1800
3 > ASD1 > fullDay > highSeason > 2000
4 > ASD1 > perWeek > lowSeason > 9000
5 > ASD1 > perWeek > midSeason > 10000
6 > ASD1 > perWeek > highSeason > 11000
7 > ASD1 > morning > lowSeason > 800
8 > ASD1 > morning > midSeason > 1000
9 > ASD1 > morning > highSeason > 1100
10 > ASD2 > fullDay > lowSeason > 2000
11 > ASD2 > fullDay > midSeason > 2200
12 > ASD2 > fullDay > highSeason > 2400
13 > ASD2 > perWeek > lowSeason > 12000
14 > ASD2 > perWeek > midSeason > 14000
15 > ASD2 > perWeek > highSeason > 16000
16 > ASD2 > morning > lowSeason > 1000
17 > ASD2 > morning > midSeason > 1000
18 > ASD2 > morning > highSeason > 1000
```

etc. etc.

What I need to do is bring back all rows from the boat_data table and join it to the boat_prices table bringing back only the lowest price for each boat. a_horse_with_no_name came up with the below solution which works perfectly. However I have now realised I also need to return the value of the pricingDescription column (fullDay,perWeek,morning etc.). I still require only the lowest price to be returned for each boat_prices row but I also need to know the pricingDescription value for that row. I've tried to solve it using the example below but I'm stumped. Any help you can give would be gratefully received. So ideally I'd have a solution for the following in the nested part of the statement:

```
select pricingref, min(price) as min_price, pricingDescription
```

***UPDATE - The seasonDescription column means that, in some cases, there will be multiple rows with the same price (see rows 16, 17 and 18 in the above example). Prices may duplicate across seasonDescriptions but never across pricingDescription for the same pricingRef.

Thanks,

Jason

```
select boat_data.*,
   t.min_price
from boat_data
join (
 select pricingref, min(price) as min_price
 from boat_prices
 group by pricingref
) t on t.pricingref = boat_data.pricingref;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select boat_data.*,
       t.price, 
       t.pricingDescription
from boat_data
join (
  select pricingref, 
         price, 
         pricingDescription, 
         row_number() over (partition by pricingref order by price) as rn
  from boat_prices
) t 
  on t.pricingref = boat_data.pricingref 
 and t.rn = 1;
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a noticable difference in using min() vs. row_number(). Probably not.

Comment: @Sam: I don't think there is a performance difference. There is a slight difference in the result: if there are two identical prices, your solution would return 2 rows for that boat, mine only one.

Comment: True. I'd prefer min() then because I'd dislike not knowing for sure what I'd get back if multiple prices are the same. row_number() is the way to go if you want a single record and don't care that it's a random one if there are multiple (though you could add more fields to the order by clause to remove the randomness).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
select boat_data.*,
   t.min_price,t.pricingDescription 
from boat_data
join (
 select pricingref, min(price) as min_price,pricingDescription 
 from boat_prices
 group by pricingref,pricingDescription 
) t on t.pricingref = boat_data.pricingref;
```

Comment: Yes. That doesn't return only the lowest price row unfortunately. It returns a row for each priceDescription in boat_prices. I need the query to return only the row from boat_prices corresponding to the lowest price value for the pricingRef

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    boat_data.*,
    b.pricingDescription,
    t.min_price
from boat_data
inner join (
    select pricingref, min(price) as min_price
    from boat_prices
    group by pricingref
) t on t.pricingref = boat_data.pricingref
inner join boat_prices b on (b.price = t.min_price and b.pricingRef = t.pricingRef)
```

Edit: I added another solution based on the information in the comments. This version should return the lowest price for each combination of pricingRef and seasonDescription (multiple rows if the same price occurs in several seasons):

```
select 
    boat_data.*,
    t.seasonDescription,
    pricingDescription,
    t.min_price
from boat_data
 join (
    select pricingref, seasonDescription, min(price) as min_price
    from boat_prices
    group by pricingref, seasonDescription
) t on t.pricingref = boat_data.pricingref
 join boat_prices b on b.price = t.min_price and b.pricingRef = t.pricingRef and t.seasonDescription = b.seasonDescription
order by pricingRef
```

Comment: Hi there. This works! Thanks for this. I've just realised something though. Sometimes there will be more than 1 row in the prices table for a pricingRef with the same price. So I need the min(price) to also be distinct. Is this possible? I'm sorry to be a pain

Comment: Do you mean that there might be several rows with the same pricingRef and price but different priceDescription? And if so do you want all rows with the lowest price or just one, and if so which one?

Comment: Hi. Not quite. I'm sorry there's actually another column in the boat_prices table which is now relevant - "seasonDescription". This will be either lowSeason, midSeason, or highSeason for each pricingRef.  So for each pricingRef row there are 3 season Description rows. In some instances the same price will occur across different seasonDescrptions for the same priceRef. Duplicate prices will never appear across different pricingRefs. In this instance the first row should show only. This could be ordered by the ID column if necessary. Do you need me to post up an updated table structure to help?

Comment: @JasonEyebe Not quite sure I understand the desired output. An updated table structure and desired output would surely help (not just me, but the other people providing answers too).

Comment: @JasonEyebe Am I right if I assume that for every priceRef there will be nine rows (3 for each season) and that you want the lowest price for each season (3 rows).

Comment: Yes that's right. I'm going to update the original question now with full info

Comment: I've just noticed your answer has been updated. This new version doesn't work unfortunately. My fault for not giving enough detail I'm sure. For clarity I don't need to return the seasonDescription value only the priceDescription value. I just need to ensure that if a pricingRef has multiple prices that are the same due to the seasonDescription, that only the first price in the table is shown. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Hmm. Both the above examples bring back multiple rows for each pricingRef (all rows associated with that ref in the boat_prices table)

Answer (score 0):

You could play around with the following:

```
select *
from
(
    select boat_data.boatDataField1,
           boat_data.boatDataField2,
           boat_data.boatDataField3,
           boat_data.boatDataField4,
           boat_prices.price,
           min(boat_prices.price) over (partition by boat_data.pricingref) as min_price,
           boat_prices.pricingDescription
    from boat_data
    join boat_prices on boat_prices.pricingref = boat_data.pricingref
)
where price = min_price
```

You can put all the fields you want to 'group by' for your min(price) in the partition by section.